# How to recover from checkpoint when using python spark direct approach?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, pyspark, spark-streaming

After read [official docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html), i tried using `checkpoint` with `getOrCreate` in spark streaming. Some snippets:

```
def get_ssc():
    sc = SparkContext("yarn-client")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 10)  # calc every 10s
    ks = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
        ssc, ['lucky-track'], {"metadata.broker.list": KAFKA_BROKER})
    process_data(ks)

    ssc.checkpoint(CHECKPOINT_DIR)
    return ssc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssc = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(CHECKPOINT_DIR, get_ssc)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The code works fine for recover, but the **recovered context always works on the old process function**. It means that even if i changed map/reduce function code, it not works at all.

Until now, spark(1.5.2) still not support arbitrary offset for python. So, what should i do to make this work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Such behaviour is "by design", and is valid also for java/scala Spark applications. Entire code is serialized while checkpointing. If code changes, checkpoint data should be truncated.

Comment: umm...I've got this. So, any idea about the right way to recover except recording offset by myself?