# Spark. Recover checkpointed RDD after driver shutdown

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I checkpointed a `rdd` which takes very long to compute. Then I executed many jobs on such a `rdd`. Eventually, one of this job failed and the driver shutdown during night. Now I need to recover the checpointed data but I can't. There are many questions like this in SO but none of them answer the question. f.e.:

[How to read checkpointed RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022313/how-to-read-checkpointed-rdd) `<=` The only answer replicates the documentation. Which Is useless

[How to recover from checkpoint when using python spark direct approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428056/how-to-recover-from-checkpoint-when-using-python-spark-direct-approach) `<=` Is about streaming context.

My enviroment is azure databricks notebooks `spark 2.4.3` and `python 3`

Comment: Certainly on topic.

Comment: That might be fatal? What about this Scala question of mine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840083/spark-checkpointing-non-streaming-checkpoint-files-can-be-used-in-subsequent-j  If u like, upvote it